# zimbra получить все письма ящика

Tags: zimbra

Подскажите, как получить все письма в ящике.

Команда типа

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@mail.com s -l 1000 in:Inbox
```

Максимум выводит 1000 писем, и даже если применять к ней grep  для сортировки

/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m $i s -l 1000 in:Inbox | grep "01/02/12"

он выдаст пустой результат, так как до даты этого письма просто не дойдет, если в ящике около 12000 писем.

Как говориться [тут](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zmmailbox)

```
search(s)                    [opts] {query}
   -v/--verbose                 verbose output
   -t/--types <arg>             list of types to search for (message,conversation,contact,appointment,document,task,wiki)
   -s/--sort <arg>              sort order TODO
   -c/--current                 current page of search results
   --dumpster                   search in dumpster
   -p/--previous                previous page of search results
   -n/--next                    next page of search results
   -l/--limit <arg>             max number of results to return (1-1000, default=25)
```

Может как то можно увеличить лимит..раньше, можно было и 9999 - но это очень давно, сейчас речь идет 7 версии zimbra.

Пробовал поставить ключ **-n/-p** - выводит пустой результат, хотя думал, что он мне выводаст предущую/следующую страницу, ну или  не понял куда надо этот ключ ставить.

Получить количество писем в папке могу

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@mail.com gaf | grep mess


   Id  View      Unread   Msg Count  Path
----------  ----  ----------  ----------  ----------
    14  mess           0        1564  /Chats
     6  mess           0          56  /Drafts
     2  mess           0        5352  /Inbox
 65450  mess           0       12433  /Inbox/до 1.04.2015
 31907  mess           0        3125  /Inbox/Маркетинг
  5993  mess           0         881  /Inbox/Юр
     4  mess           0           0  /Junk
     5  mess           0        7527  /Sent
```

А вот получиь все сообщения - не могу...

Поясню для чего это, может решение с другой стороны: Нужно удалить письма, котрые были 4 года назад, и как писал выше, при выводе в 1000 писем, не получаю всех нужных писем.

Подскажите куда смотреть...

Answer (score 2):

Вот небольшой сдвиг

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@mail.com s -t mess "Date: 06/25/12"
```

Но пока не понял как сюда приплести регулярные выражения

А вот так можно получить сообщения до нужной даты

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@mail.com s -t mess "before: 01/01/13"
```

Но при этом, нельзя указать папку - он по всем смотрит

Вот так вывод будет именно переписок, Conversation

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@mail.com s -t conv "before: 01/01/13"
```

но вывод будет только 20, для увеличения списка ставим -l 1000 -  уже получше, тут хотябы в рамках даты...